# Issue with integrating Bootstrap template into Angular application - select('#header') returning null

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to integrate a Bootstrap template into my Angular application, but I've run into an issue with the scrolling behaviour. In the Bootstrap template's `main.js` file, there is a function that adds the class `header-scrolled` to the header element based on scrolling. This function seems to work perfectly in the standalone template, but when I try to use it within my Angular application, the `select('#header')` function returns `null`, causing the scrolling behaviour to break.

Here are the steps I followed for integration:

1. I copied the template's `assets` into the assets directory under the `src` directory of my Angular application.
2. In `angular.json`, I added the path to the `main.js` file in the scripts array.

Here's the code snippet from the main.js file of the Bootstrap template:

```js
const select = (el, all = false) => {
  el = el.trim();
  if (all) {
    return [...document.querySelectorAll(el)];
  } else {
    return document.querySelector(el);
  }

  let selectHeader = select('#header');
  if (selectHeader) {
    const headerScrolled = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 100) {
        selectHeader.classList.add('header-scrolled');
      } else {
        selectHeader.classList.remove('header-scrolled');
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('load', headerScrolled);
    onscroll(document, headerScrolled);
  }
};
```

I suspect that the issue might be related to the Angular application's component lifecycle or the timing of when the `select('#header')` function is called.

Can anyone help me understand why the `select('#header')` function is returning null in the context of an Angular application? Are there any specific considerations or modifications needed to make this function work within Angular?

Comment: You need wait Angular paint. This is generally in AfterViewInit lifecycle of the component. If you call to this function before, you don't "reach" the element. The solución is generally enclosed all this instructions in a function and call the function in ngAfterViewInit

Comment: @Eliseo What you mean by enclosing all the instruction, Do you mean enclose everything in the `main.js` into a single function and then call the function inside  `AfterViewInit`? Which component should implement the `AfterViewInit`. The `app.component.ts` ?

Comment: The component/s where you have the `id="header"`